# Map between skyscraper sheaves - Görtz-Wedhorn Ex. 7.7

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Görtz-Wedhorn's Ex. 7.7 (p. 204), we are asked to consider $X= \mathrm{Spec} A$ for some integral domain $A$ with quotient field $K$ and generic point $\eta \in X$. Now it is easy to see that the skyscraper sheaf $\mathscr F^x$ with value with value $K$ is an $\mathcal O_X$-module for any $x \in X$. The exercise claims that there exists a canonical injective morphism of $\mathcal O_X$-modules $\mathscr F^x \to \mathscr F^\eta$ for any $x \in X$.
I do not see how this map should exist: If we take any open $U \subset X$ with $x \not \in U$, the square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathscr F^x(X)=K @>>> \mathscr F^\eta(X) = K\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathscr F^x(U)=0 @>>> \mathscr F^\eta(U) = K
\end{CD}
just does not commute. Thank you for any help!

Comment: I was following this question. Maybe you can send a message to Görtz and Wedhorn to have a clarification ? You can find their email addresses here https://www.algebraic-geometry.de/ (same page for the list of errata). I would be happy if you update this question with their answer.